# Point and Print Restrictions Not Applying

Tags: group-policy, printing

I'm trying to deploy some printers in my organization via GPO. I tried first through Computer Configuration < Policies < Windows Settings < Deployed Printers, and now I'm trying through Computer Configuration < Preferences < Control Panel Settings < Printers.

The server is running Windows Server 2012 and the client machines are Windows 10.

When I try to deploy printers I get error 0x80070bcb, "The specified printer driver was not found on the system and needs to be downloaded." However, I've set my point and print restrictions to not require a UAC prompt, and the users are local admins. Even when I use File Explorer to navigate to the print server and connect to a printer, I'm presented with a UAC prompt for drivers.

I've set the Point and Print restrictions setting first to enabled with no UAC prompt and later tried the disabled setting without luck, (under Computer Configuration, I know it used to be under User User Configuration but isn't any longer). Checking with gpresult shows that the Point and Print Restrictions are successfully applying to the client machines, and there are no contradicting GPOs. This GPO is attached to the correct OU, as evidenced by the gpresult report.

Any idea what's going on? I can't seem to get the client machines to allow printer drivers to install/skip the UAC prompt when done manually.

Comment: Please take a look at this thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/4stcdo/kb3170455_stops_nonadmin_users_from_installing_a/

Comment: I saw that thread, and that's how I ended up enabling point and print restrictions with the specified settings. However, the client machines seem to ignore even those settings.